# Split recurring payment with Stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm creating a website to let users split the cost to rent things. I need to charge users monthly, splitting the total payment between x users. What is the best way to do this with Stripe?

From looking at the documentation, I've seen Stripe Connect has [multiple charge types](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges) including 'separate charges', which let you split a one-time charge between multiple users. However, I don't see a way to split recurring charges - the [subscriptions page](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions) doesn't mention separate charges, and I don't see a way to split a subscription fee.

The only way I can think of to do this is to build separate Stripe products for every possible split between people. For example, if the monthly rental cost is $600, I could create one product for a 2 person split ($300), one for a 3 person split ($200), and so on (up to at least 10 people). The problem with this is I have several things on the site, all with different rental costs, so I would have to create hundreds of different Stripe products. I'd also like to be able to adjust rental costs if needed, which would mean recreating all these split products. Is there a better way to do this? I'm open to using another platform but would prefer Stripe since I'm familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following the problem. How would you do it for a one time charge?
Retain the info and submit it monthly.
This has the advantage of leaving you in control of the recurring charges, since it sounds like your splits will be changing more often than what I think if as a typical subscription.

Comment: You're saying to just make a one time charge every month? That would solve my problem, I was just hoping there was a built-in way to do it.

Comment: Sure. That would make sense. Perhaps they haven't had requests for it. Perhaps they haven't gotten to it. But either way, I think that long term, you'll be better off having the control on your side.

Comment: And remember the fundamental rule, 0, 1, or infinity.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule